# How to create a Package Repository - hosted on github pages

Tags: ubuntu, debian, github-pages, apt, apt-get

Any one know how to create Debian packages to distribute on Ubuntu?

I have looked at:

https://earthly.dev/blog/creating-and-hosting-your-own-deb-packages-and-apt-repo/#pgp-gpg-and-gnupgp

https://assafmo.github.io/2019/05/02/ppa-repo-hosted-on-github.html

Totally new on Linux packaging, trying to distribute an executable for different architectures.

1 - Created a control file in DEBIAN

```
Package: hello-world
Version: 0.0.1
Maintainer: example <example@example.com>
Depends: libc6
Architecture: arm64
Homepage: http://example.com
Description: A program that prints hello
```

2 - Generated a .deb file

```
dpkg-deb -b ./hello-world
```

3 - Created a Package file

```
dpkg-scanpackages -m . > ./Packages
```

4 - Generated a key

```
gpg --full-gen-key
```

5 - Created a Release file

```
Origin: Example Repository
Label: Example
Suite: stable
Codename: stable
Version: 1.0
Architectures: arm64
Components: main
Description: An example software repository
Date: Mon, 02 Aug 2021 17:37:16 +0000
MD5Sum:
6c6d..c7
SHA1:
372...acf5
SHA256:
b06041...94655e
```

6 - Created a list file

```
deb [trusted=yes] <url>
```

7 - pushed to github - and using github pages

8 - installed

```
curl -s --compressed "https://<user>.github.io/<url>/KEY.gpg" | sudo apt-key add -
sudo curl -s --compressed -o /etc/apt/sources.list.d/my_list_file.list "https://<user>.github.io/<url>/my_list_file.list"
sudo apt update
```

### many different errors

```
Unable to locate package hello-world
```

or
Ubable to passe file
etc.

Anyone know how to create a Package Repository?